# Trying to set an ID for an element using knockout.js and getting undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to knock out and fairly new to JavaScript so apologies if I have done something silly here...

I am using knockout.js (3.4.2) to maintain a list of dependents, I have the add and delete working OK but I want to set an ID on an element to allow me to make it read only. 
I have based my code to do this on the knockout example, their working example can be seen here: [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zacmarshall/qzuzgv4o/)

When I run my code the ID is set to undefined:

```
<input data-bind="uniqueId: dependantName, value: dependantName" id="undefined" type="text">
```

My code on JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/zacmarshall/khb13ha4/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="javascripts/vendor/knockout-3.4.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascripts/vendor/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<head>


<body>

    <input data-bind="value: newDependantName" />
    <input data-bind="value: newDobDD" />
    <button data-bind="click: addDependant">Add</button>

    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data, null, 2)"></pre>

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date of Birth</th> 
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="qualifications-summary" data-bind="foreach: dependants">
            <!--div data-bind="uniqueId: dependantName"-->
            <div>
                <tr>

                    <td><label data-bind="uniqueFor: dependantName">Before</label>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="uniqueId: dependantName, value: dependantName"/>
                    </td>
                    <td><input data-bind="value: dobDD" /></td> 
                    <td><input data-bind="value: itemIndex"/></td> 
                    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.removeDependant">Remove</a></td>

                </tr>
            </div>
        </tbody>

    </table>

</body>
```

javascript:

```
function Dependant(data) {
    this.itemIndex = ko.observable(0);
    this.dependantName = ko.observable(data.dependantName);
    this.dobDD = ko.observable(data.dobDD);
    this.readOnly = ko.observable(data.readOnly);
    this.showEditButton = ko.observable(data.showEditButton);
}



function DependantListViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.dependants = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.newDependantName = ko.observable();
    self.newDobDD = ko.observable();
    self.readOnly = ko.observable();
    self.showEditButton = ko.observable();
    self.itemIndex = ko.observable();

    var i = 0;

    // Operations
    self.addDependant = function() {


        var data1 = {   itemIndex : (i),
                        dependantName : this.newDependantName(), 
                        dobDD : this.newDobDD(),
                        readOnly : "readonly",
                        showEditButton : (!0)
                        };
        self.dependants.push(data1);
        self.newDependantName("");
        self.newDobDD("");
        i++
    };
    self.removeDependant = function(dependant) { self.dependants.remove(dependant) };

    self.editDependant = function(i) {
        console.log("editedDependant");
        self.readOnly(undefined);
        self.showEditButton(!1)
    };
    self.saveDependantItem = function(self) {
        self.readOnly("readonly"), self.showEditButton(!0)
    };

}

ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId = {

    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value.id = value.id || ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.prefix + (++ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.counter);
        console.log("in handler");
        element.id = value.id;
    },
    counter: 0,
    prefix: "unique"
};


ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueFor = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        value.id = value.id || ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.prefix + (++ko.bindingHandlers.uniqueId.counter);

        element.setAttribute("for", value.id);
    } 
};

ko.applyBindings(new DependantListViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug refers to this in your `init`:

```
var value = valueAccessor(); // this is undefined
value.id = value.id // therefore this falls over
```

This is the issue:

`self.dependants.push(data1);`

It should be:

`self.dependants.push(new Dependant(data1));`

And then update your `Dependant` model to pass the index:

`this.itemIndex = ko.observable(data.itemIndex);`

Here is a working [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7k2me5z0/)

Comment: Thank you. This has also resolved the issue of changes on the screen not being reflected in the array straight away. Looking at the examples I had of multiple columns per row they didn't update straight away so I had thought this was how it worked and I was going to have to export the array (for some reason it exported the up to data info even though it didn't show it when changed).